# BackgroundWorker ou Async

Tags: c#, winforms

Preciso desenvolver um programa em C# onde vou ter processos lentos.

Tenho pouca experiência com WinForms, tenho mais experiência com desenvolvimento WEB.

Estou com a seguinte dúvida, o componente BackgroudWorker faz a mesma coisa que chamar a função assincronamente?

Se não, onde devo utilizar um e onde devo utilizar o outro?

Comment: Depende. O que você quer dizer com "chamar a função assincronamente"?

Comment: cara um [tópico](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414601/async-await-vs-backgroundworker) bom que explica o que você quer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...BackgroudWorker faz a mesma coisa que chamar a função assincronamente?

Sim, **[BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx)** é uma classe que executa uma operação em outra *thread/background*. Além disso permite você checar informações durante a execução da *thread*, cancelar/interromper a *thread*, normalmente usado em eventos de interface Windows Form.

A partir do .Net Framework 4.5 foi incluído suporte a ***[async](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx)*** programming, que além de suportar as características/*features* do BackgroundWorker permite um código mais legível, usado em *Task Parallel Library* (TPL) para simplificar o paralelismo e a concorrência nas aplicações.

> ...onde devo utilizar um e onde devo utilizar o outro?

A menos que você precise usar uma versão mais antiga do C#, sugiro usar *async* e *await*.